# Check once a function is complete

Tags: jquery

I have a lit of offsets for a div that I load when a link is clicked to give a comic book style effect.  Each offset activates other animations to give a more dynamic feel.

I am now looking to change it so that to move from offset 0 to offset 2 will move via offset 1.  To add to the complexity, I don't want the secondary animations at offset 1 to go off in this instance.

The problem, therefore, is that I need to activate the sliding function and then activate it again once the current one is complete.  Is there a way for me to know this?  Also, is there an easy way to reverse the animation so it will occur the next time they go to that offset?

If I am going about this the wrong way, please feel free to tell me.

Comment: Please provide code or create a jsfiddle

Comment: question makes zero sense to anyone that can't see your code and a demo would definitely help

Comment: jQuery animations are naturally sequential. `$(selector).animate(cssMap_1).animate(cssMap_2).animate(cssMap_3);`

Comment: I can't use this as I will be dynamically constructing a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the core of your problem is the flow of the javascript code. You will want to use a callback function. If you add a callback variable to a function, you can execute code after the function has run its course:

```
function foo(callback) {
    // some code you want to execute

    // then run the callback function
    if (typeof(callback) == "function")
        callback();
}

function bar() {
   // some code you want to execute after foo is finished
}
```

Now you can run `bar()` after foo is complete like this:

```
foo(bar);
```

Comment: Not quite what I needed in the end, but remarkably well put now that I understand a little more.  Just a side not, wouldn't I need to call 'foo(bar());'?  Or do I not need () when calling a callback function?

Comment: `foo(bar())` would pass the `return` of `bar()` to `foo()`. You want to pass the function itself which is `bar`. Another way to think about it is `foo(function(){ bar() })`.

Answer (score 0):

If you utiilise the `.data('obj',{currentPosition:index});`  approach, you can create a `.data()` object on an element and have your animations query it to see 'where' they are from 0 to however many items you need in your comic book sequence.  Base your animations on the index from 0=>however many and then update the `currentPosition` when your animation is finished using the callback parameter in the animation.

Would that direction help?  If you can give some example code (simple or otherwise) we might be able to see a way to tie it in?